# Getting "input signal out of range", nomodeset doesn't fix

Tags: debian

Hi I installed Debian on my computer to dual boot but when I try to boot into linux it doesn't output anything and says "input signal out of range". I tried setting "nomodeset" in linux launch options but it doesn't work. I also tried to do "gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub" while logged into root user w/ safe mode but it says "Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:". Someone suggested I use a non-free repository with drivers but I don't quite get how to use it. I have a GTX 1060 GPU.

Comment: Decrease the resolution of your display and set the frequency to 60 Hz.

Comment: My frequency was already at 60hz and I tried to lower the resolution but it still does not work.

Comment: Try a command-line editor: `emacs`, `nano`, `vi`, … with plain `sudo` instead of `gksudo`. Trying to use graphical programs when experiencing graphical problems is an recipe for frustration. Ctrl+Alt+F2 should get you to a text console if you don't already have one